# For all sets $A,B$ and $C$, if $B \cap C \subseteq A$, then $( A\smallsetminus B) \cap (A\smallsetminus C) = \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that this is true.

This is my current process. If $B$ AND $C$ are subsets of $A$, then everything in $A$ has elements of $B$ and $C$. So, if we were to remove all of $B$ AND all of $C$ from $A$, then there would be nothing left.

I'm not sure how to set that into a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{1,2,5\}$, $C=\{2,3,6\}$. Then $B\cap C=\{2\}\subseteq A$ and $(A-B)\cap (A-C)=\{3,4\}\cap\{1,4\}=\{4\}\ne\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Hagen has already provided a valid counterexample. This is to make you realize you mistake.

1. $B\cap C\subseteq A$ does **not** mean $B,C$ are both subsets of $A$; this, admitting I took you right (and "is subsets" is definitely ungrammatical), is a big mistake: it is the *intersection* that is a subset, not the *union*; neither $B$ nor $C$ are necessarily subsets;
2. In any case, being a subset of doesn't mean coinciding with; that is, $B\cup C\subseteq A$ does **not** mean $B\cup C$ *is* $A$: there might be elements outside that union but still in $A$; so the "everything" argument is plain wrong.

Of course, if you assume $B\cup C=A$, then you claim holds. That is because:

$$(A\smallsetminus B)\cap(A\smallsetminus C)=(A\cap B^C)\cap(A\cap C^C)=A\cap B^C\cap A\cap C^C=A\cap(B^C\cap C^C)=A\smallsetminus(B\cup C)=A\smallsetminus A=\varnothing.$$

Naturally it is enough to assume $A\subseteq B\cup C$ to have that proof.

In fact, the above works if $A,B,C$ are all subsets of a bigger set. A proof by contradiction is formally better if you don't assume such a common ambient set. Suppose $x\in(A\smallsetminus B)\cap(A\smallsetminus C)$. Then $x\in A$, but $x$ is neither in $B$ nor in $C$, so $x\in A$ but $x\notin(B\cup C)$, but $A\subseteq(B\cup C)$, contradiction.